# GTK popup menu position in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk, gtk3

I would like my pop-up menu is placed under the `GtkToggleButton` not at current mouse position Gtk pop-up menu is created on `GtkToggleButton` click.  See my example below:

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I would like to have:

[image: What I would like to have]

How can I accomplish the latter?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of GtkToggleButton you have to use [GtkMenuButton](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuButton.html) or [GtkMenuToolButton](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuToolButton):

```
"The GtkMenuButton widget is used to display a menu when clicked on."

"GtkMenuToolButton — A GtkToolItem containing a button with an additional dropdown menu."
```

[GtkMenuButton](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuButton.html) is available since GTK+ 3.6, you can check the [demo in the documentation](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-devel-docs/log/platform-demos/C/samples/menubutton.py).